# How to Display Datatable Contents into a datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple DataTable, How can i display everything inside it into gridview?

```
public void BindData(DataTable tbl)
{
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = (...)?
}
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
gridview.datasource=tbl;
```

Comment: Databind() has to be called in case of web forms. We don't need it for Windows forms. Setting DataSource will solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

sqldataadapter.fill(tbl);
DataGridView.Data Source = tbl
(higher numbered rows not accessible)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).